# Jetty: socket connection as websocket connection

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, jetty

I'm pretty new to websocket programming (or better: web programming at all).
A while ago I made something using Sockets and ServerSockets to exchange data between a client and server and now I started to build something with similiar functionality using WebSockets and jetty but can't figure it out until now.

So what I'm aiming to do at the moment is: the client got a string message, sends it to the server using a websocket and the server is just pasting out that message (to console or to a file).
General context: I got 2 applications running on different machines and want to use websockets to exchange some data between them.

So that's my client's code :

```
public class SocketClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            new SocketClient().run(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/"));
            //new SocketClient().run(new URI("wss://localhost:8443/"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void run(URI destURI) throws Exception {
        WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
        try {
            client.start();
            ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();

            ExampleSocket socket = new ExampleSocket();
            Future<Session> future = client.connect(socket,destURI,request);

            future.get();

            socket.getRemote().sendString("hello server"); 
        }
        finally
        {
            client.stop();
        }
    }
}


class ExampleSocket extends WebSocketAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void onWebSocketText(String message)
    {
        try
        {
            getRemote().sendString(message);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And that's my server code:

```
public class SocketServer extends AbstractHandler {
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            baseRequest.setHandled(true);

            response.getWriter().println(request);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(new SocketServer());

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

I got both mostly from the jetty documentations but can't figure it out until now. When I try running them together I get that error on my client:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: Didn't switch protocols
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:123)
    at SocketClient.run(SocketClient.java:37)
    at SocketClient.main(SocketClient.java:19)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: Didn't switch protocols
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.validateResponse(UpgradeConnection.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.read(UpgradeConnection.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.onFillable(UpgradeConnection.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So thanks a lot in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSocket client needs WebSocket server. What you did in server is to add a handler to deal with HTTP request-response exchanges only. You need to allow Jetty to deal with WebSocket resources by registering a servlet of `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet` or an endpoint of `javax.websocket.Endpoint`.

Here's [working examples](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples) written by Jetty team. If you are not a fan of JSR, take a look at native-jetty-websocket-example.

Anyway, Jetty team will give you definite answer if this answer is incomplete as they are watching jetty tag.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion that I was missing something. Tried to solve it using an Endpoint which was getting me a bit closer to the solution. At the moment we try to solve the whole issue a bit differently, so it's considered solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is true that you need a websocket for client and a websocket for server endpoint. I've encountered same problem, but I all things got clear when I followed this example, from 4.6 below:

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-websocket-example/

Whoever has this problem, try to look carefully at that link, it will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There may be the server started in secure connection mode and trying to connect with non secure URL or vice versa. This can be the root cause of this exception.